# Is there any opposite function of array_map() in PHP?

Tags: php, callback, array-map

Array_Map applies callback to all elements of a supplied array. I want to know if there is any function that applies an array of callbacks to any mixed variable (or all elements of an array)?

For example, `array_map` works as:

```
function array_map( $callback , $array )
{
    foreach( $array as $value )
    {
        $callback( $value );
    }
}
```

I want a native function that works like:

```
function multi_callback( $callbacks , $mixed )
{
    foreach( $callbacks as $callback )
    {
        if( is_array( $mixed ) )
        {
            array_map( $callback , $mixed );
        }
        else
        {
            $callback( $mixed );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in or standard extension function, likely because it's too close in functionality to `array_map`. Note that for a scalar value, it can be implemented as a single `array_map` call:

```
array_map(function ($f) use($scalar) {
        return call_user_func($f, $scalar);
    }, $callbacks
);
```

With the advent of [arrow functions](https://www.php.net/functions.arrow), it's even shorter:

```
array_map(fn ($f) => $f($scalar), $callbacks);
```

`multi_callback` could be implemented in terms of `array_map`. One change that should be made for performance is to move the `is_array($mixed)` branches outside of the loop/`array_map` callback, as it doesn't change over iterations (moving loop-invariant statements outside of loops is a standard optimization). Also, don't forget those return statements.

```
function map_all(array $functions, $value) {
    return array_map(fn (callable $f) => $f($value), $functions);
}

function multi_callback(array $callbacks, $mixed) {
    if (is_array($mixed)) {
        return array_map(fn ($value) => map_all($callbacks, $value), $mixed);
    } else {
        return map_all($callbacks, $mixed);
    }
}
```